# NSPopover Not Appearing

Tags: cocoa, coordinates, popover

I really wish I could be more specific, but unfortunately, I cannot. All appropriate objects are non-nil, and all appropriate method calls are going through (presumably) successfully, but my `NSPopover` just never shows up. None of the delegate methods get called, either.

```
// ivars
NSPopover *tagPopover;
NSViewController *tagPopoverViewController;

// in method to display popover
tagPopover = [[NSPopover alloc] init];
[tagPopover setBehavior: NSPopoverBehaviorApplicationDefined];
[tagPopover setDelegate: self];
tagPopoverViewController = [[MYViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"MYViewController" bundle: nil];
[tagPopover setContentViewController: tagPopoverViewController];
[tagPopover setContentSize: tagPopoverViewController.view.frame.size];

[tagPopover showRelativeToRect: NSMakeRect(700, 400, 5, 5) // Screen coordinates
                        ofView: [[NSApp keyWindow] contentView]
                 preferredEdge: NSMinYEdge];
```

Comment: @Monolo, yes `-awakeFromNib` is called fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the coordinate system was wrong:

```
NSRect theRect = [[NSApp keyWindow] convertRectFromScreen: NSMakeRect(700, 400, 5, 5)];
[tagPopover showRelativeToRect: theRect // Window Coordinates
                        ofView: [[NSApp keyWindow] contentView]
                 preferredEdge: NSMinYEdge];
```

Needed to convert it to the window's coordinate system first.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that `tagPopoverViewController.view.frame` is NSZeroRect, since frames are set to that before they start to go onscreen (e.g. they are meaningless as they come out of xibs/storyboards). Are you sure you need that line? The documentation mentions that the contentSize is bound to the content-view's size anyway.

Comment: Or, a somewhat dirty hack, call `view` on the view controller right after the initialization to force a load of the view.

Comment: Nope: `tagPopoverViewController.view.frame: {{0, 0}, {281, 118}}`

Comment: @Monolo the line `tagPopoverViewController.view.frame.size` *does* call view ;-)