# How to position NSPopover

Tags: cocoa, nsview, nsoutlineview, nsviewcontroller, nspopover

I have an OSX application that uses NSViewController to swap in-out views in my NSView. One of the views is a NSOutlineView. I now want to have a NSPopover appear when the user double-clicks a row in the outlineview.  Currently I use the [following approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495082/nspopover-not-appearing) to have the popover appear:

```
NSRect theRect = [[NSApp keyWindow] convertRectFromScreen: NSMakeRect(700, 400, 5, 5)];
[myPopover showRelativeToRect: theRect // Window Coordinates
                        ofView: [[NSApp keyWindow] contentView]
                 preferredEdge: NSMinYEdge];
```

This makes the NSPopover appear at the bottom of the app. This works but I want to be able to have the popover appear exactly below the clicked row of the NSOutlineView. Every view I swap in-out is controlled by a NSViewController and I thought I could identify my view positions using the view property of the NSViewController. However, if I replace `[[NSApp keyWindow] contentView]` with `myViewController.view` I receive the error that view does not have a window and the NSPopover crashes. Clearly, I have trouble 1) finding the coordinates of the clicked row in the NSView relative to the main window 2) understanding why my view does not have a window. If anyone has suggestions that could help me understand these problems I would greatly appreciate it.

UPDATE 06/02/2013
I am still struggling with my problem but I have discovered that I can get the correct coordinates for my view if I access its properties through my MainWindowController (myControlledView). When I then ask for the origin and frame size of my view I get the correct values. My VC's load the custom view as a NIB file and when I ask for the origin of the loaded view I get (0,0). I thought that the position of the view relative to the window would remain unchanged even if I load the view as a NIB? I can pass the view origin to my VC and thereby set the NSPopover correctly but this seem rather cumbersome and I would think the NIB loaded view origin was correctly accessible through the VC.

```
managingViewController *vc = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:[viewIndex intValue]];
[self.currentViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
[self setCurrentViewController:vc];
[self.myControlledView addSubview:vc.view];
NSLog(@"My origin: %f %f",vc.view.frame.origin.x,vc.view.frame.origin.y);
```

This results in`:My origin: 0.000000 0.000000` and is not what I am looking for, while this:

```
NSLog(@"My origin: %f %f",self.myControlledView.frame.origin.x,self.myControlledView.frame.origin.y);
```

Results in the correct origin: `My origin: 176.000000 38.000000`

Clearly there is something about views and windows I dont understand. Any help is apreciated.

Thank you for suggestions and help! Cheers, Trond

Comment: You say that you're using an NSViewController to swap views in and out (somehow) of an NSView. Which view is the VC's? If it's not the parent view you're swapping views in and out of, then what view *does* the VC own? Which of these, if any, did you add to the view hierarchy of the window?

Comment: I use several VCs to control the content of my NSView which is added to my superview. When I swap view I call the following methods:managingViewController *vc = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:[viewIndex intValue]];
   [self.currentViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self setCurrentViewController:vc];    [self.myControlledView addSubview:vc.view];

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This turned out to be quite easy as soon as I understood what I was doing. It turns out I had two allocations of my currentViewController. One was allocated in IB while one was allocated in code. When I deleted the IB created VC I could interact with the correct code initiated view and I was able to position my NSPopover using the position of the (tracked) mouse:

```
-(void)mouseMoved:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    NSPoint p = theEvent.locationInWindow;
    self.myMouseX=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:p.x];
    self.myMouseY=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:p.y];
}
```

The mouse position was used to define the coordinates for my rect:

```
NSRect theRect = NSMakeRect([self.myMouseX floatValue] + 5,[self.myMouseY floatValue],1,1);

[myPopover showRelativeToRect: theRect // Window Coordinates
                       ofView: [[NSApp keyWindow] contentView]
                preferredEdge: NSMaxXEdge];
```

Cheers, Trond